# "About this App" login text and settings

Tags: facebook, dialog, fbconnect

I'm using single-sign-on under iOS for my app, but I think my question relates to the other platforms as well. I need to change the "About this App" text in the login dialog, but changing the text in the various properties according to [this Facebook Docs page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/) results in no change. I'm saving my text in the Description field. How long do the settings take to propagate?

Comment: It should be under the App Details -> Descriptions field. The text you enter there should show up in the login dialog. Are you saying that's not happening ?

Comment: It appears to have taken effect, but for no apparent reason. I think there needs to be more clarification that the Description field corresponds to that 'About this App' login text.